# Use field label as placeholder in django-crispy-forms

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-crispy-forms

I'm thinking about the DRY way to use field labels for placeholder attribute of my `<input>` HTML elements. I'm using `django-crispy-forms`.

Right now I have:

```
class FilterForm(Form):

    query = CharField(max_length=50, label='', required=False)

    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('query', placeholder='Search ...'),
        )
        super(FilterForm, self).__init__(data, files, **kwargs)
```

I'd prefer, however, not to have to set label and placeholder separately, as this for will eventually have many more fields and it's quite verbose.

What are your suggestions?

Comment: This doesn't feel non-DRY to me.  It's two different things: Defining `label` as an empty string, and then defining `placeholder` with text.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

A DRY solution could be achieved with this **__init__** method:

> ```
> def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
>     super(FilterForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
>     helper = self.helper = FormHelper()
>
>     # Moving field labels into placeholders
>     layout = helper.layout = Layout()
>     for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
>         layout.append(Field(field_name, placeholder=field.label))
>     helper.form_show_labels = False
> ```

Comment: This is the best solution. @realefab I had to use `self.helper = FormHelper(self)` rather than `...= FormHelper()`. Works on Django 1.8.2 and DCF 1.4.0.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, hiding labels can be achieved by using the [bootstrap helper attribute](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form_helper.html#bootstrap-helper-attributes) below:

> self.helper.form_show_labels = False
>
> Default set to True. It decides wether to render or not form’s fields labels.

You still need to define the placeholder using the Field layout object:

> Field('query', placeholder='Search ...'),

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
class FilterForm(Form):

    query = CharField(max_length=50, label='', required=False)

    def __init__(self, data=None, files=None, **kwargs):
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('query', placeholder=kwargs.pop('query_placeholder', 'random text')),
        )
        super(FilterForm, self).__init__(data, files, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 3):

This DRY solution doesn't require modification of the layout.  I suggest making it a mixin:

```
class MyForm(Form):

    _placeholders = {
        'fieldname': 'fieldname placeholder',
    }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        # Assign placeholder to widget of fields
        # listed in self._placeholders.
        for field_name, field in self.fields.items():
            if field_name in self._placeholders:
                self.fields[field_name].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = \
                self._placeholders[field_name]

        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Nice, since it does not depend on Crispy Forms.

Answer (score 1):

You can add extra attributes to your form fields by using:

```
query = CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Search..'}),
                  max_length=50, label='', required=False)
```

Comment: @Centralniak: Are you looking for this?

Comment: Sorry, no. I'm looking for crispy forms usage explicitly. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just hiding the field labels using css. It's a bit hackish, but works. I still used placeholder="your label" to define the placeholders though.

Answer (score 0):

There is the widgets field if you want more control

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        widgets = {
            'comment': forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows': 6, 'placeholder': 'Enter your comments'}),
        }
        labels = {
            "private": "Keep Private",
        }
        exclude = ['response', 'display']
```