# add a placeholder in these fields django

Tags: django, placeholder

I'm really confused how to use placeholders. I'm using model that has a couple of fields of data and I want to have a place holder telling he user what to enter. So placeholder sounds like a good way to put this info into the text field. I'm using Crispy forms and fields come from the model.

Here is my forms.py just don't know how to incorporate placeholders here if its even here where I need to do it.

```
from django import forms
from .models import MRReg

class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MRReg
        fields = ['SiteID','HeliumValue']

    def clean_HeliumValue(self):
        HeliumValue = self.cleaned_data.get('HeliumValue')
        #HeliumValue_base, provider = HeliumValue.split("@")
        #domain, extension = provider.split('.')
        #if not extension == "edu":
            #raise forms.ValidationError("Please use a valid .edu address")         
        return HeliumValue
            #print (self.cleaned_data)
    def clean_SiteID(self):
        SiteID = self.cleaned_data.get('SiteID')
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please enter a valid SiteID")

        return SiteID
```

Comment: Possibly a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482753/use-field-label-as-placeholder-in-django-crispy-forms - can you check that question to see if it answers this one?

Answer (score 0):

If you use forms widgets like `forms.CharField` you can pass this to it, for example `forms.CharField()`

```
forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'my-placeholder'}))
```