# Django forms - how to add labels inside boxes?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-crispy-forms

I have simple django- form:

```
class ContactUsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('subject', 'email', 'message')
        widgets = {'time': forms.HiddenInput()}
        labels = {
            'subject': 'my_subject',
            'email': 'my_email',
            'message': 'my_message',
        }
```

Model:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    message = models.TextField()
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.message
```

And html:

```
<h2 class="mb-5">Contact</h2>
{% load crispy_forms_filters static %}
<form method="POST" class="post-form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Send</button>
</form>
```

How to remove labels above boxes and put it inside? Is it possible to do it with crispy?

Answer (score 2):

Try this !

```
class ContactUsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    subject = forms.CharField(label='Subject', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Subject'}))
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'}))
    message = forms.TextField(label='Message', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Message'}))
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ('subject', 'email', 'message')
```

Comment: remove label tag in forms.py class to remove labels from above boxes in html page

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available in crispy forms. The question below shows a dry way of achieving this using the **init** method

[Use field label as placeholder in django-crispy-forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482753/use-field-label-as-placeholder-in-django-crispy-forms/23971724#23971724)